# PageSpeed Insights: Shows "blocking" when resource has been deferred

Tags: javascript, pagespeed, deferred, pagespeed-insights

I am working on "*Reduce the impact of third-party code*" in PageSpeed Insights. The biggest offender is LiveChat so I moved it into GTM and deferred it by setting its trigger to 0.5s after page load. The network panel and the [waterfall chart on GTMetrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMtao.png) are showing LiveChat is deferred. But, when I run a test on PageSpeed Insights, it shows that [LiveChat is blocking the main thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvKxQ.png) for 222ms (desktop) and 1,410ms (mobile).

Does anyone have any insight as to why this might be happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The waterfall chart is not helpful in identifying items that are blocking the main thread, it is used to show network activity.

The main thread is related to **CPU processing time.**

On page speed insights it listens out for "CPU quiet" time to get an idea of when the page has finished its initial render (this is not the same as when something has been downloaded, JavaScript still needs to be parsed and executed).

This diagnostic item is there for JavaScript heavy pages as a potential performance improvement (as mobile CPUs are a lot slower than desktop ones and a lot of JS can cause noticeable delays and stuttering while being parsed and executed).

As it is doubtful that you will be able to do much about the efficiency of the script or payload weight etc. there is little you can do (you could delay the script about 3 seconds instead of 0.5 seconds to ensure all critical JS has been executed, or you could load the whole LiveChat initialisation to a button click event if you want to minimise potentially redundant code down the wire).

You have to bear in mind this sits under the "diagnostics" section, so **it doesn't directly affect your score**, it is there to help you identify symptoms of a low score (mainly the "time to interactive" and "total blocking time" metrics.)

If you are scoring above 90 / 100 and still want to improve your speed score then it would be worth exploring alternatives or implementing conditional loading of the Scripts etc. based on a button click as I mentioned earlier, if you are scoring below 90 / 100 there will be other easier opportunities for improvement.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I don't have enough rep to upvote your answer, but I appreciate it.

Comment: Not a problem, welcome to stack overflow, glad it helped!